# Dimensions of picture files through excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, jpeg

I'm trying to get the dimensions of picture files. All of the paths are listed in an excel column and the hope is to populate another column with the files dimensions. My attempt gets the error

> Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set

on the line

`Set objfile = objfolder.parsename(filename)`

Any and all help welcome...I'm a beginner.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filedimensions As String
    Dim prefilename As Integer
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 7
    filepath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Do Until IsEmpty(filepath)
      filepath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
      prefilename = InStrRev(filepath, "\")
      folderpath = Left(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, prefilename)
      filename = Right(filepath, Len(filepath) - prefilename)
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(folderpath)
      Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(filename)
      filedimensions = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 17).Value = filename
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 21).Value = filedimensions
      i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Without knowing what the value of `folderpath` is, I'm going to guess it has something to do with this line - `Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(folderpath)`

Comment: Please learn how to step thru your code using `F8` and how to use your immediate window to check all your variables. When you are a self-proclaimed beginner and you use code that has a lot of `Object` variables, the error messages are going to be really confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  The path looks something like this: S:\GGG\advantage\uploads\expand\my stuff\fun stuff\07398.jpg
I'll be working on this some more today and get back with any updates.

Answer (score 2):

This error means an object you're trying to use contains, in VBA parlance, Nothing.

Knowing the line where you get the error, look at the object you're trying to use: `objFolder`. Where is `objFolder` assigned? On the line just above. Why isn't it assigned something else than Nothing? Because `objShell.Namespace` returned Nothing. Why did `objShell.Namespace` return Nothing? Because the folder doesn't exist.

Here's your code with a couple modifications to help you out. As mentioned by @braX, `F8`, the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) plus breakpoints work wonders.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filedimensions As String
    Dim prefilename As Integer
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'Moved this line out of the loop; assigning once is enough.
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    i = 7
    filepath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Do Until IsEmpty(filepath)
      filepath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
      prefilename = InStrRev(filepath, "\")
      folderpath = Left(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, prefilename)
      filename = Right(filepath, Len(filepath) - prefilename)

      Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(folderpath)

      'Check whether objFolder resolved to something.
      If objFolder Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Folder not found: " & folderpath, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Note"
      Else
        Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(filename)

        filedimensions = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 17).Value = filename
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 21).Value = filedimensions
      End If

      i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  Paths look something like this: S:\GGG\advantage\uploads\expand\my stuff\fun stuff\07398.jpg
I am getting nothing value with objFolder and will be experimenting more today.